# I want to open a file that depends on the variable "NewFileName". I'm trying to concatenate it with the path of its location. Using VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, windows, openfiledialog

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Dim theName As String
        'Dim counter As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
        Me.Hide()
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Projects\Test")
        For Each foundfile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Projects\Test")
            Dim testFile As System.IO.FileInfo
            testFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(foundfile)
            Dim FileName As String = testFile.Name
            Dim FileNameEdited As String = Replace(FileName, ".DWG", "")
            Dim NewFileName As String = FileNameEdited & "_" & TextBox1.Text & ".DWG"
            MsgBox(FileNameEdited)
            Dim check As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(foundfile)
            If check = ".DWG" Then
                'My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Projects\Test" & FileName, NewFileName)
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Projects\Test" & NewFileName)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first up, I don't see any place where you actually rename the file. I recommend the `MoveTo` method on `FileInfo`, like this:

```
testFile.MoveTo(NewFileName)
```

Then, your concatenation of the new file name to the hard-coded path is incorrect. You need the backslash at the end. Let's suppose `NewFileName` held the value `Fleex_main.DWG`: you would be trying to start `C:\Projects\TestFleex_main.DWG`. The concatenation operator knows nothing about paths and is just going to shove two strings together. That line should be:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Projects\Test\" & NewFileName)
'                                                 ^ very important
```

As a final note, if you read the introduction to StackOverflow, you will see that it is strongly encouraged that you ask a specific question and reduce the problem to just the lines that do wrong things. Code dumps make life harder for people who want to help you.